# warning in using loadlibrary function

Tags: matlab, loadlibrary

I’m trying to use `loadlibrary` function but it shows me a warning:

```
loadlibrary('test1.dll', 'testheader.h')
```

> Warning: Warnings messages were produced while parsing.  Check the
>   functions you intend to use for correctness.  Warning text can be
>   viewed using: [notfound,warnings]=loadlibrary(...) In loadlibrary at
>   374

i use visual c++ 2008 and matlab R2008a 32 bit

Any suggestions on what is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

No idea what the *specific* problem is since you haven't actually provided the warnings.

However, I *can* tell you that, when a build system says something like `"do A to get more information"`, I generally find that it's a good idea to do `A`.

In other words, change the line as suggested:

```
[notfound, warnings] = loadlibrary('test1.dll', 'testheader.h')
```

and then examine those two things to see what the actual problem was. See [here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/loadlibrary.html) for details, paraphrased below:

> The snippet
>      `[NotFound, Warnings] = loadlibrary ('SharedLib.dll', 'HeaderFile.h')`
>  returns warning information from the `SharedLib.dll` library file.
>
> `NotFound` is a cell array of the names of functions found in the header file `HeaderFile.h`, or any header added with the "addheader" option, but not found in the `SharedLib.dll` library.
>
> `Warnings` contains a single character array of warnings produced while processing the header file `HeaderFile.h`.